# How to get uploaded file from clientside in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm using the npm multer module in my nodejs file to get formdata from the clientside, which contains the image that I upload from my computer. However, when I try to print out the file on the server side, it is undefined, which I'm guessing that the file wasn't actually sent to the server. When I print it out on the client side, it is there.

main.js (clientside)

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", file);
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", "/post");
r.send(formData);
```

app.js (server side)

```
var multer = require('multer');

var upload = multer({dest:'./pics/'});

app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually *use* the middleware. For example:

```
app.post('/post', upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file);
});
```

Comment: Forgot about that. Thanks!